# Make a rectangle blink

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I just flicker (blink) a rectangle shape in an HTML Canvas?

```html
function Addrect() {
var red = new fabric.Rect({top: 300,
left: 100,
top: 800,
width: 350,
height: 350,
cornerSize: 40,
fill: 'green'
});
canvas.add(red);
}
```

Merci à vous ;)

Comment: Please use correct case shift.

Comment: Try using a `timer` and an IF statement. The timer adds a delay before doing something (eg: adjusting the RGB colour or opacity of your `red` rectangle). To adjust you need to access the colour part of your rectangle. Try using `red.fill="blue";` before using `canvas.add(red);` did it change colour? That's the same logic of timer (IF green make it blue, ELSE do vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let counter = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    context.fillStyle = (counter % 2 === 0) ? 'blue' : 'white';
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 80, 80);
    counter++;
}, 1000);
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```